# making double readable by adding '.' , ',' , trimming (not rounding) so only 2 last digits possible?

Tags: java, string, formatting, double, currency

I've been looking for a way to convert a double, which is big to a readable String.
The double:

```
 double myValue = 1000000000000000.123456789;
```

Which when printed out gives me this:

```
 1.0000000000000001E15
```

The result im looking for would be this:

```
1.000.000.000.000.000,12
```

I've been searching for this for days but i couldn't find a solution for this unfortunately so i thought maybe i could ask here:) thanks for reading!

Comment: `System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(myValue).setScale(2));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in setting your own separator characters (i.e. not using the default for your locale) then you can do the following:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');
symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00", symbols);
System.out.println(format.format(100000000000.123456789));
```

You also mentioned rounding in your question. Unfortunately that has nothing to do with the formatting at all - you are hitting the limit of precision for `double` in Java. A `double` is a 64 bit floating points which gives you 15-16 digits of precision. You can verify this by checking the following expression in Java: `1000000000000000.123456789 == 1000000000000000.1`.

So, in reality what is happening is that once you have assigned your value to the `myValue` variable it has already been rounded. It doesn't matter how you format it from that point you won't get the precision back.

If you need greater precision than `double` you should look at `BigDecimal` that supports arbitrary precision.

Comment: oh woooow thanks a lot was searching for this so long!<3

Comment: just found out it still rounds up at some point, is there a way to disable rounding?

Comment: I'll add a comment about that to my answer